# Google maps позиция

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Подскажите , как реализовывается такая вещь:
Есть блок, где выбирается город, к примеру Москва и Лондон
И мне нужно
 1) указать в каждом городе метку офиса
 2) при нажатии на город ( в блоке ) перемещаться на определенную метку

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать Маркеры Google Maps API.

Это довольно просто, вот пример кода:

```
// инициализация гуглокарты
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  // параметры инициализации карты
});

// параметры - координаты офиса
// lat - широта
// lng - долгота
function chnangePositionOnMap(lat, lng) {
  var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

  /* это чтобы поставить маркер если нужно
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'текст маркера'
  });
  */

  // а это чтобы перейти к данным координатам на карте
  map.setCenter(myLatLng);
}
```